# Odd problem with the Multivariate Input Multi-Step LSTM Time Series Forecasting Models

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have developed Multivariate Input Multi-Step LSTM Time Series Forecasting Models for my dataset according to the tutorial (https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/).

Yet, I had a very odd problem, that is, when I run code with smaller samples (50 samples for training, 10 samples for testing), the predictions are correct. but when I run the experiment with full samples (4000   samples for training, 1000  samples for testing),  the predictions contain NaN values, which lead to errors.

Then, when I try scaling plus relu activation functions plus regularization as following code, I can get predictions with full samples (4000  samples for training, 1000  samples for testing), but the predictions is still not correct, I want to forecast 96 steps, but all steps I predicted is the same number.

Can you give a useful suggestion to deal with the forecast accuracy issues?

```
import time
from math import sqrt
from numpy import split
from numpy import array
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import RepeatVector
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
import csv
import numpy
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from numpy import save
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def scale(train, test):
    # fit scaler
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    train = train.astype(float)
    test = test.astype(float)
    scaler = scaler.fit(train)
    # transform train
    train = train.reshape(train.shape[0], train.shape[1])
    train_scaled = scaler.transform(train)
    # transform test
    test = test.reshape(test.shape[0], test.shape[1])
    test_scaled = scaler.transform(test)
    return scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled

# split a univariate dataset into train/test sets


def split_dataset(data):
    # split into standard weeks
    train, test = data[0:387030, 10:26], data[387030:433881, 10:26]
    # train, test = data[0:4850, 10:26], data[4850:5820, 10:26]
    # train, test = data[0:387030], data[387029:433880]
    # restructure into windows of weekly data
    # numpy.savetxt("test.csv", data[387030:433881, :], delimiter=",")
    # save('test.npy', data[387030:433881, :])
    scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled = scale(train, test)

    train_scaled = array(split(train_scaled, len(train_scaled) / 97))

    test_scaled = array(split(test_scaled, len(test_scaled) / 97))
    return scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled

# create a list of configs to try


def model_configs():
    # define scope of configs
    # n_input = [12]
    n_nodes = [100, 200, 300]
    n_epochs = [50, 100]
    n_batch = [64]
    # n_diff = [12]
    # create configs
    configs = list()
    # for i in n_input:
    for j in n_nodes:
        for k in n_epochs:
            for l in n_batch:
                cfg = [j, k, l]
                configs.append(cfg)
    print('Total configs: %d' % len(configs))
    return configs

# evaluate one or more weekly forecasts against expected values


def evaluate_forecasts(actual, predicted):
    scores = list()
    # calculate an RMSE score for each day
    for i in range(0, actual.shape[1], 97):
        # for i in range():
        # calculate mse
        mse = mean_squared_error(actual[:, i, :], predicted[:, i, :])
        # calculate rmse
        rmse = sqrt(mse)
        # store
        scores.append(rmse)
    # calculate overall RMSE
    s = 0
    for x in range(actual.shape[0]):
        for y in range(actual.shape[1]):
            for z in range(actual.shape[2]):
                s += (actual[x, y, z] - predicted[x, y, z])**2
    score = sqrt(s / (actual.shape[0] * actual.shape[1] * actual.shape[2]))
    return score, scores


# convert history into inputs and outputs


def to_supervised(train, n_steps_in, n_steps_out=97, overlop=97):
    # flatten data
    sequences = train.reshape(
        (train.shape[0] * train.shape[1], train.shape[2]))
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(0, len(sequences), overlop):

        end_ix = i + n_steps_in

        out_end_ix = end_ix + n_steps_out
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if out_end_ix > len(sequences):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :], sequences[end_ix:out_end_ix, :]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)

    return array(X), array(y)

# train the model


def build_model(train, n_input, config):
    # unpack config
    n_nodes, n_epochs, n_batch = config
    # prepare data
    train_x, train_y = to_supervised(train, n_input)
    # define parameters
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, n_epochs, n_batch
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2], train_y.shape[1]
    # reshape output into [samples, timesteps, features]
    train_y = train_y.reshape((train_y.shape[0], train_y.shape[1], n_features))
    # define model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(
        LSTM(
            n_nodes,
            activation='relu',
            input_shape=(
                n_timesteps,
                n_features), recurrent_dropout=0.6))
    model.add(RepeatVector(n_outputs))
    model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.6))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_nodes, activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_features)))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    # fit network
    model.fit(
        train_x,
        train_y,
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        verbose=verbose)
    return model

# make a forecast


def forecast(model, history, n_input):
    # flatten data
    data = array(history)
    data = data.reshape((data.shape[0] * data.shape[1], data.shape[2]))
    # retrieve last observations for input data
    input_x = data[-n_input:, :]
    # reshape into [1, n_input, n]
    input_x = input_x.reshape((1, input_x.shape[0], input_x.shape[1]))
    # forecast the next week
    yhat = model.predict(input_x, verbose=0)
    # we only want the vector forecast
    yhat = yhat[0]
    return yhat

# evaluate a single model


def evaluate_model(train, test, n_input, cfg):

    start = timer()

    # fit model
    model = build_model(train, n_input, cfg)

    # print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    # history is a list of weekly data
    history = [x for x in train]
    # walk-forward validation over each week
    predictions = list()

    for i in range(len(test)):
        # predict the week
        yhat_sequence = forecast(model, history, n_input)
        # store the predictions
        predictions.append(yhat_sequence)
        # get real observation and add to history for predicting the next week
        history.append(test[i, :])
    # evaluate predictions days for each week
    predictions = array(predictions)

    # invert scaling

    predictions = predictions.reshape(
        (predictions.shape[0] *
         predictions.shape[1],
         predictions.shape[2]))
    predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

    test = test.reshape((test.shape[0] * test.shape[1], test.shape[2]))
    test = scaler.inverse_transform(test）


    predictions = array(split(predictions, len(predictions) / 97))

    test = array(split(test, len(test) / 97))
    score, scores = evaluate_forecasts(test, predictions)
    run_time = timer() - start
    return cfg[0], cfg[1], cfg[2], score, scores, run_time


# load the new file
dataset = read_csv(
    'data_preproccess_5.csv',
    header=0,
    index_col=0)
# split into train and test
scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled = split_dataset(dataset.values)
# evaluate model and get scores
n_input = 7 * 97

# model configs
cfg_list = model_configs()

scores = [
    evaluate_model(
        train_scaled,
        test_scaled,
        n_input,
        cfg) for cfg in cfg_list]
```

provide some sample data
[sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KnZAj0eyGWkKKBo24J2GxCrybvs43apc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Their should be a lot of problem in the other parts of your code, which us not here. Like e.g.  your y reshaping which the linked example doesn't contain etc. So provide them or we can not help based on this info.

Comment: @Geeocode Thanks for your comments, I have posted the full code, can you give a help? thanks very much

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @Geeocode Thanks for following up, please find the sample data, thank you very much

Comment: Welcome, please insert the first part of your code with imports etc.

Comment: @Geeocode Thanks, I have inserted the code

Answer (score 1):

If you have multistep output, you can easily reshape your predictions and calculate it.

#### My splitted datasets

```
`trainX, trainY, testX, testY`
```

#### Get Prediction Results

```
`trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)`
`testPredict = model.predict(testX)`
```

#### Reshape the Predictions and Real Values

```
`trainY = trainY.reshape(-1, )`
`trainPredict = trainPredict.reshape(-1, )`

`testY = testY.reshape(-1, )`
`testPredict = testPredict.reshape(-1, )`
```

#### Calculate root mean squared error

```
`print('Train Root mean squared error: {}'.format(math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY, trainPredict))))`
`print('Test Root mean squared error: {}'.format(math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY, testPredict))))`
```